# Adjustable height of light fixture

Tags: light

I would like to be able to adjust the height of this grow bulb as my plant gets larger.

Can someone give me some ideas?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please check the temperature of our lampshade, that cord looks like ready to go up in flames if that shade gets hot (like many do.)

Comment: The temp is fine. Hard to see in the picture, but the bulb is a series of leds. It draws little current and the heat output is low.

Answer (score 5):

You have it attached to a fixed bracket, but if you replaced the bracket with a twin-slot bracket bar:

[image: Bracket bar]

You could keep adjusting it.

Comment: +1 This nice hack looks neat and solves the problem elegantly. Furthermore, the bar can be attached to the plant table (both can be moved easily as a unit) or to the wall as you show for a fixed location for the plants.

Comment: @Stan Good idea Or this. https://imgur.com/a/mjxNWug